# How to add search results from an action to the user interface in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have adopted a simple Ember app. Currently, I load a set of locations via the model method on the route like this:

```
Hex.LocationsbysectionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/all-locations").then( function(response){
      return response.map(function (child) {
        return Hex.Location.create(child);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to add a search button at the bottom to add locations to a specific section. I understand that I could use transitionTo but I'd just like to place this into the DOM somehow - this seems really simple but having a hard time finding a working example online.

Something like:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="locationsbysections">
    <input id='hex-ember-location-val' /><button {{action 'searchForLocations'}}>search</button>
  </script>
```

But I'm not really sure how to handle the `searchForLocations` action and get the results into the UI. Would I use the model on the Route? I was thinking something like this but how would I deliver the Promise to the template?

```
Hex.LocationsbysectionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    searchForLocations: function() {
      var query=$('#hex-ember-location-val').val();
      $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/locations/query_by_sections/" + query).then( function(response){
        var items=[];
        $.each(response, function(idx, val){
          var location=Hex.Location.create(val);
          items.push(location);
          console.log(location);
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I'm able to put this into the items array but how would I render that into the original locationsbysections template? It doesn't seem like the `model` method of the Router is the place to do this but how would I get this to work?

I have tried something like this:

```
{{#if hasSearchItems}}
  <div>there are {{items.length}} search resutls!!!</div>
  {{#each items}}
    <div>{{name}}  <button {{action "addToSection" this}}>add to section</button></div>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <div>there are no search results</div>
{{/if}}
```

and then manage the `hasSearchItems` variable in the Controller, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use real ember-data model you can eventually leave model empty and set your property in setupController:

```
Hex.LocationsbysectionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {return null},
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/all-locations").then(function(response) {
            var locations = response.map(function (child) {
                return Hex.Location.create(child);
            });
            controller.set("locations", locations)
        });
    }
}

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="locationsbysections">
    {{#each location in locations}}
        <div>{{location.name}}</div>
        etc...
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

In this manner you can overwrite your `locations` property without problems.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="locationsbysections">
    ...
    {{input type='text' value=searchInput}}
    <button {{action 'searchForLocations'}}>search</button>
</script>


Hex.LocationsbysectionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchInput: "",

    actions: {
        searchForLocations: function() {
            var that = this;
            $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/locations/query_by_sections/" + that.get("searchInput")).then(function(response) {
                var locations = response.map(function (child) {
                    return Hex.Location.create(child);
                });
                that.set("locations", locations)
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: cool, let me take a look at this but makes sense. just a closure / scoping issue. have a ton of things on my plate rest of week so might be awhile. but thx!